# How to boot Windows 7 UEFI recovery partition?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, uefi, qemu

I've got an image of a hard drive that won't boot from within a Qemu VM. I managed to get UEFI working using [OVMF](http://www.tianocore.org/ovmf/), but it still won't give me an option to boot the recovery partition. Given that I have access to the partition and `file` tells me about it that it's:

```
$ sudo file /dev/loop5 -s
/dev/loop5: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 472590336, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 27527167, $MFT start cluster 786432, $MFTMirror start cluster 2, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number 0ae2cb5312cb4f605
```

Is there a way I could somehow make qemu boot from this partition or copy it to a second hard drive so that I would boot it instead? Just copying /dev/loop5 to rec.img and trying to boot it via qemu didn't work.

Comment: can you load your Windows ISO and try to repair it within Qemu?

Comment: @hkdtam: not really, I don't have such ISO with my laptop.

Comment: Only Windows 7 64-bit supports UEFI mode.  There is no such thing as an "UEFI" partition, I assume you mean GPT, or perhaps the FAT32 EFI partition.  The reason I say something UEFI and EFI are two related but seperate things.

Comment: Does your image contain a valid partition table, and an EFI system partition?

Comment: @JeremyKerr: yup.